# Text in custom QWebEngineView is not shown when run from link

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I have a custom `QWebEngineView` named `MyWebWidget`, where I set html code, that contains links. When I click one link, a `QDialog` opens. In the dialog Window there is another `MyWebWidget`. But in the PopUpWindow no text is shown in `MyWebWidget` and I have no idea why. When I use `QTextEdit` instead of `MyWebWidget`  or `QWebEngineView` the text is shown. Below is a minimal example to reproduce the error.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
from MyWidgets import MyWebWidget

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.widget = MyWebWidget()
        self.widget.setHtml('<a style="text-decoration:none;" href="data:link">link</a>')
        self.widget.link.connect(self.function)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

    def function(self, link):
        dialog = MyPopUpWindow(link, ["abcd"])
        dialog.exec_()

class MyPopUpWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, title, inputList):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        labelWiget = QLabel()
        labelWiget.setText(title)
        webWidget = MyWebWidget()
        text = ""
        for i in inputList:
            text += str(i)
        webWidget.setHtml(text)
        layout.addWidget(labelWiget)
        layout.addWidget(webWidget)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`MyWebWidget` looks like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from MyWidgets import MyWebEnginePage
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class MyWebWidget(QWebEngineView):
    link = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        page = MyWebEnginePage(self)
        self.loaded = False
        self.content = ""
        # connect to the signal
        page.dataLinkClicked.connect(self.handleDataLink)
        self.setPage(page)
        # use a data-url
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finished)

    def on_load_finished(self):
        self.page().runJavaScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML", self.callback)

    def callback(self, r):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
        if not self.loaded:
            self.content = soup.text.strip()
            self.loaded = True

    def handleDataLink(self, text):
        self.link.emit(text)
```

MyWebEnginePage looks like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MyWebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):
    dataLinkClicked = pyqtSignal(str)

    def acceptNavigationRequest(self, url,  _type, isMainFrame):
        if (_type == QWebEnginePage.NavigationTypeLinkClicked and
            url.scheme() == 'data'):
            # send only the url path
            self.dataLinkClicked.emit(url.path())
            return False
        return super().acceptNavigationRequest(url,  _type, isMainFrame)
```

Comment: Did you try to: 1. Show a standard QWebEngineView (not your subclass) in the dialog? 2. Use properly written HTML code, not just plain text?

Comment: Using QWebEngineView nor using properly written HTML code does not work either. Also loading a QUrl does not work. Nothing is shown on the QWebEngineView in the dialog window.

Comment: What about using `open()` instead of `exec()` (after properly setting a reference to it to avoid garbage collection)?

Comment: that works. But why?

Comment: I think it might be related to nested event loops (remember thar `exec` starts an event loop for the dialog, "blocking" the main one). It *could* be a bug, but I'm not completely sure. Also, try setting the parent for the dialog (which is always recommended for modal dialogs).